# using python's 'with' while reading two files simultaneously with izip

Tags: python-2.7, python-itertools, with-statement

I regularly use python to read two or more files simultaneously in the following way:

```
for line1, line2 in izip(open(file1),open(file2)):
    do something with line1 and line2
```

(using izip from the itertools package because the files I'm reading are huge and I don't want to load the entire file into memory).

I have recently been converted to using `with` while reading files, which is apparently better since it will close all open files if your program crashes (at least that's what I understand from discussion on here and other places):

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        do something with line
```

however, I can't seem to figure out how to combine these two methods. When trying to use izip in this context, it says `'itertools.izip' object has no attribute '__exit__'` which I intuit is part of the reason why using `with` is so powerful.

So, is there anyway to use `izip` with `with`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll kick yourself when you see how obvious it is :

```
with open(fname1) as f1, open(fname2) as f2:
    for line1, line2 in izip(f1, f2): 
        ...
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `with open(names[0]) as f1, open(names[1]) as f2: SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (note the syntax error seems to be picking up the comma for some reason)

Comment: Well I can't explain that, the syntax is correct.  Check the previous line for errors, sometimes the parser gets it off by one.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, the same code works on a different machine... Do you know if there is there any dependency on python version? It seems to work with python 2.7, but not on a machine running python 2.6

Comment: I don't know, I thought with statement was available in 2.5 with a `from __future__` import, and was already there in 2.6.  That version is almost 10 years old and I couldn't be bothered to install it just to check this ..   :)

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help anyway. I'll post back on here if I end up figuring out what the deal is.